# Why is there a difference between using a lambda in a where extension method an using a func in a where extension method

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm reading programming entity framework by Julia Lerman 2nd edition 
I have a question about example 3-5 page 63

the code in the book

```
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts5 = context.Contact.Where(c => c.FirstName == "Robert").OrderBy(foo => foo.LastName);

foreach (Contact contact in contacts5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("De voornaam is {0} en de achternaam is {1} ", contact.FirstName.Trim(), contact.LastName);
}
```

results as expected

But when I try

```
Func<Contact, bool> whereDel = c => (c.FirstName == "Robert                                            ");
Func<Contact, bool> whereDel1 = c => (c.FirstName == "Robert");
Func<Contact, string> orderDel = foo => foo.LastName;
IEnumerable<Contact> contacts6 = context.Contact.Where(whereDel).OrderBy(orderDel);

foreach (Contact contact in contacts6)
{
    Console.WriteLine("De voornaam is {0} en de achternaam is {1} ", contact.FirstName.Trim(), contact.LastName);
}
```

I get the expected results only with WhereDel. For the predicate I copied one of the roberts from the datatable in the sample database. 
With whereDel1 which is the same predicate as the lambda in the where clause in the example in the book I get an empty IEnumerable. 
Anyone?

Comment: the `Where` expects an `Expression<Func<Contact, bool>>`, which is different from a `Func<Contact,bool>`

Comment: You do realize that you're pulling down the entire table into memory in order to filter the collection using LINQ to objects, rather than doing the filtering on the database, yes?

Comment: if you use expression you will get the same result as before. I suggest you also look at the queries that are being issued to the database and watch for unexpected results.

Comment: I don't know whether this will help you, but tere is a difference in how LINQ works for in-memory objects and for the EF (they are two different "LINQ providers"). Basically, LINQ-to-objects takes delegates and uses them to create iterators for each "operator" you use. LINQ-to-entities needs to receive expression trees, in order analyze them and produce an equivalent query for the underlying DBMS (SQL, for example).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And yes i'm realizing there is an entire table in memory but i'm just following the examples studying entity framework.

Comment: The difference between `whereDel` and `whereDel1` isn't clear, since you've got a syntax error there. What does the code really look like?

Answer (score 2):

EntityFramework needs an `Expression` of `Func`, not just `Func`. That's how it gets the expression tree it needs to convert your C#-ish code to SQL.

`IQueryable` only implements the overloads with `Expression` of `Func` (`Func` is already compiled, while `Expression<Func>` is not). When you use the overloads with `Func`, you're using the `IEnumerable` methods - and that means executing the whole queryable, and applying the `Where` on the results, rather than adding them to the SQL.

The fix is rather simple:

```
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> whereDel = c => c.FirstName == "Robert";

var contacts = Contact.Where(whereDel);
```

Now, why would the two cause you to get different *results*, rather than just performance? Despite what EntityFramework is attempting to do, C# *isn't SQL*. There's differences between how things are evaluated, for example on MS SQL, the default string comparison is case insensitive, while C#'s is sensitive - so doing `FirstName == "Robert"` will also work for `robert` on MS SQL, but not in C# (the `IEnumerable.Where` variant). Another example would be comparing two `char` values (as opposed to `varchar`) - for `char(8)`, `FirstName = 'Robert  '` will work in SQL, but not in C# (you need to trim both sides first).

Comment: While true, that won't cause it to not work.  It just results in the work being done on the application, not in the database.

Comment: @Servy Updated to include how this can cause differences in evaluation of the query.

Comment: After all these years, I started to think if it would be better if `IQueryable<T>` did not implement `IEnumerable<T>` at all.

Comment: @tia Yeah, I totally agree. For all the "LINQish" providers I've implemented, I haven't implemented `IQueryable` at all. You don't *have to* be `IQueryable` to use LINQ - thankfully, it's very much duck-typed. It's still a very wide interface (e.g. forcing you to handle everything that any .NET language can throw at you, ouch), but at least it's less susceptible to annoying issues like this. Of course, you can no longer be part of another `IQueryable` and use `IQueryable`s helper methods etc.